# a question a bout plot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot 3-D figure in matlab.
I know how to use plot3 and surface. But now I have a vector and no a matrix.
Actually I have $(x,y)$ and $u(x,y)$ that $u(x,y)$ is obtained after solving my problem. 
when I using plot with mesh, my figure is not true.
please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you put a grid in two vectors x and y, then you could do the following.

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Comment: Thanks. But $u$ is $78\times 1$. I constructed a $78\times 78$Matrix  but my figure was not true. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Hakha You said that U is 78x1. How could that be? If either of x or y is constant, then you do not need a 3d plot but rather a 2d plot.

Comment: I have two vector $78\times 1$  $X and ~~Y$ and by these I construct vector $u(x,y)$

Comment: @Hakha Ok, for that case, just look at my edit.

Comment: @Learner If x and y are vectors of length $n$ and $Z$ is and $n\times n$ matrix, then you can use 'surf(x,y,Z)'. Surf will treat this as the set of triplets (x(i), y(j), Z(i,j)). This is especially important when $n$ is large as the two matrices produces by meshgrid are much larger.

Answer (score 1):

You have two vectors that define the sample points in x and y. To get all the points in the x-y domain you can use MESHGRID, as was suggested by learner. MESHGZRID will do a Cartesian product of the two sets X and Y. Then you can use those points to generate your function $u(x,y)$. Then you can use the full domain of x and y to plot u. Showing this with an example function $u(x,y) = x + y$ (note the case difference in variable names):

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
u = X + Y;
surf(X,Y,u)
```